# MySQL improve query syntax

Tags: mysql, performance, join

I have this simple MySQL query:

```
SELECT * FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2 ON table2.col = table1.id
WHERE table1.id = '123'
```

`id` is the primary key in `table1`.

`table2` has composite primary key of two columns: `col` and `col_two`.

Now I ran `EXPLAIN` on the above query to see how it performs and got the following rows:

```
id select_type table   type  possible_keys  key     key_len  ref    rows Extra
1  SIMPLE      table1  const PRIMARY        PRIMARY 8        const  1
1  SIMPLE      table2  ref   PRIMARY        PRIMARY 8        const  1    Using index
```

From my understanding, `ref` would be used if the join matches multiple rows but I'm using `WHERE` with a constant value. So, shouldn't the join have a `const` type like the `table1` query?

I'm worried that this would cause performance issues on a large scale. Is there a way to improve the above query or it's already good enough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2
ON table1.id = '123' AND table1.id = table2.col;
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE id = '123') A
INNER JOIN
(SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE col = '123') B
ON B.col = A.id;
```

Answer (score 1):

The `ref` isn't referring to a constant, it's comparing two columns from two tables. Using the `=` operator will result in the `ref` type for `table2.col = table1.id`.

For a query this simple, it's hard to recommend any improvements without knowing data sizes, indexes, both table structures, etc. I would say that the `SELECT *` isn't generally advisable unless you absolutely need to return all columns.

If you have any examples of more complex iterations of the query, then there might be more than can be said.

Comment: i'm not selecting all cols...this is just for the same of simplicity :)